# How to pass column name as parameter in select statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to pass column name as parameter in a SQL Server `select` statement?

Comment: We need much more info to understand the question...

Comment: My table consist of multiple columns and about 30 columns have similar data. I need to select 1 column data randomly. So that i have to send column name as parameter in select statement. How can i achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: You will need to use **dynamic SQL** to achieve this - basically building the SQL statement *as a string* inside your code, and then replacing your column names with parameters. SQL Server **cannot** use parameters for table or column names by default, in "static" SQL

Answer (score 7):

You will need to build up the query to execute dynamically, but you will need to protect against SQL Injection attacks.  Fortunately, SQL Server provides the [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function for this purpose.

```
DECLARE @columnname varchar(50)
SET @columnname = 'MyColumn'

EXEC('SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@columnname) + ' FROM MyTable')
```

Comment: thanks Richard - had forgotten about quotename. Deleted my answer since you already posted

Answer (score 2):

You can use method:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'your dynamic query here'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Please note this is unsafe and not recommended to use.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Load]
@tablename VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

EXEC('SELECT  max(date) AS MaxDate, min(date) AS MinDate from '+@tablename)

END