# How to parametrize a dynamic query in Go

Tags: postgresql, go, prepared-statement, psql

Users can request product prices based on a number of different criteria, which will result in it potentially accessing different columns in a table. I'm looping through the requested products and building a bunch of queries, but am running into some trouble.

Running them one by one and combining the results takes a much longer time than unionizing them. So I tried building the query like follows, which works and is fast, but is now susceptible to injection.

Is there a better way to do this without the Union? Or is there a simple way I could parametrize a dynamic query like this?

```
    var fullQuery string
    var counter int
    for i, d:= range dataMap{
    if counter != 0 {
        fullQuery = fullQuery + " UNION "
    }
    var records string
    for _, p := range d{
        records = records + `'` + string(p) + `',`
    }
    recordLength:= len(records)
    if recordLength> 0 && records [recordLength-1] == ',' {
        records = records[:recordLength-1]
    }
    counter++
    fullQuery = fullQuery + fmt.Sprintf(`
SELECT 
    price_`+fmt.Sprint(p.type)+` as price,                
  FROM products
  WHERE products.id in (%s) and products.store= %s
  
`, records, p.store)

}

err := sqlx.Select(db, &dataStruct, fullQuery)
```

So, in some situations, I might have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    price_`+fmt.Sprint(p.type)+` as price,                
  FROM products
  WHERE products.id in (%s) and products.store= %s
```

And in others (depending on the request), I might have something like this:

```
SELECT 
    price_`+fmt.Sprint(p.type)+` as price,                
  FROM products
  WHERE products.id in ('testid1', 'testid2') and products.store= 2
UNION
SELECT 
    price_`+fmt.Sprint(p.type)+` as price,                
  FROM products
  WHERE products.id in ('testid3', 'testid4') and products.store= 1
```

If I knew for sure what the query was, I would just use $1, $2, etc.., but I don't think I can here because I don't know how many parameters there will be and they all need to be different.

Comment: Is it really a question about how to do that using the `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` package (there's a tiny glimpse of that fact in your question) and/or with (some unnamed) PostgreSQL driver for Go (based on the question tag)? Please be more specific.

Comment: You can't parameterize column names in SQL. But column names are more easy to sanitze   in your backend code anyway because all the names are known upfront. They dont have dynamic values like true values. So you could make something like a map with known valid column names and see if the user input is in that map. If its in the map you know its valid and cant cause any harm because only a small selection of pre-defined values (the column names) is allowed.

Comment: Or you try to go for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120527/9208887. So I was not entirely correct with my statement that you can't parametrize column names. I am not sure how easy it would be to include multiple column names like this and so on.

Comment: @TheFool To clarify, I'm not trying to parametrize the column names, but rather the product Ids and the store value. (the %s replacements).

I'll update initial question with some more info.

Comment: You are surely parameterizing the column name. Or what would you call this `SELECT 
 price_+fmt.Sprint(p.type)+` ? If you don't sanitize p.type properly, then you have a potentially injection vulnerability.

Comment: @TheFool There is already validation in place for everything and additional validation in place for the column names that are being used. I just wanted to parametrize the values for the added security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, rough untested example of how I ended up doing it in case anyone else runs into this.

```
 var counter int = 1
 var parameters []interface{}

 for _, d:= range data{
    if counter != 1 {
        fullQuery = fullQuery + " UNION "
    }
    fullQuery = fullQuery + fmt.Sprintf(`
SELECT 
    price_`+fmt.Sprint(d.type)+` as price,                
  FROM products
  WHERE products.id = ANY($%v) and products.store= $%d
  
`, counter, counter+1)
   counter+=2
   parameters = append(parameters, pq.Array(d.ids), d.store)

}

err := sqlx.Select(db, &dataStruct, fullQuery, parameters...)


Will still need to validate column names prior to querying to prevent injection.
```